# Do some plant proteins have no domains?

Tags: botany, proteins, gene

I've always been under the impression that all proteins consist of at least one domain (with the exception of intrinsically disordered proteins). However, I've come across some things which challenge that while reading some papers and I'm not sure how to understand it. From one paper (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tig.2006.09.003);

> We determined the tendencies for individual protein functional (Pfam)
> domains to occur among duplicates or singleton genes (see the
> supplementary material online) resulting from independent GD events
> that occurred 60 and 70 MYA in the lineages of Arabidopsis (a) [15]
> and Oryza (r) [16], respectively. Analysis of Pfam domains as the
> experimental unit also permitted us to compare these angiosperm events
> with GDs in yeast [20] and Tetraodon [21]. Between 1334 and 1704
> domain types were found in the four organisms, with duplicated genes
> containing an average of about one domain and singletons averaging
> 0.15–0.40 domains (see Table 1 in the supplementary material online).

If the average singleton in the genomes of the organisms under study here have 0.15-0.40 domains, that means the majority have no domains. Checking the supplementary material confirms this. In a second paper (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gpb.2016.06.003), Figure 6 shows that both rice and humans have a substantial number of proteins without any domains.

What is the meaning of this? How can these proteins have no domains? The best explanation I can come up with is simply that this data is a possible artifact resulting from simple lack of detection by domains were based on the specific database being used (Pfam in one case and InterPro the other), but I'm not sure if this is the correct understanding of this.

Comment: I suspect you are confusing two different things — from your quote it seems likely that the paper is talking about the subset of domains that are *defined* in the Pfam database. My understanding is that most proteins have never been studied and their existence is inferred from DNA sequences. This means that unless the inferred proteins have detectable homology to a characterized protein they won't have a *defined* domain. This is not the same thing as them not having one or more structural domains ...

Comment: Makes sense. So, in this context, is there a clear significance to that singletons have a lower defined domain frequency than duplicated genes?

Comment: Hard to see what it might mean, but since I don't have time to read the paper I'd be unwilling to say that it didn't mean *something*. Could be just that duplicated proteins are by definition more common and thus more likely to have been studied, but there may be something deeper like them being (on average) less essential (due to the duplicate) and so easier to study/recover mutations ... if you are sure (based on rereading the paper) that the interpretation in my first comments is correct, you could [edit] this question to focus on what you just asked and see whether anyone has an answer ...